# Repeat condition over columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of 14 columns and thousands of rows. I want to count or select rows where value in column 1 is 0 and more than 0 in the other 13 columns, then count those were value is 0 in second column and more than 0 in the other 13 columns and so on for all 14 columns. 
Any hint on how to do that ?

Many thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show efforts to solve the problem yourself first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The first line is to replicate the data and the second line shows the counting result based on your logical expression

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(14, sample(0:5, 1000, replace = T)))
result <- sapply(1:14, function(i) {sum(df[,i]==0 & apply(df[-i]>0, 1, all))})
names(result) <- paste0("Col_", 1:14)
result

Col_1  Col_2  Col_3  Col_4  Col_5  Col_6  Col_7  Col_8  Col_9 Col_10 Col_11 Col_12 Col_13 Col_14 
 12     12     19     15     18     20     19     13     19     15     12     17     15     18
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the function `apply`? If you write a function that reads a vector of length 14 and and outputs `T` or `F` depending on whether the vector satisfies the requirement, then you can use `apply` to apply this function to all rows of the data.frame, yielding a vector of thousands of `T`s and `F`s that can be used for selecting or counting (the latter by simply putting the vector into the `sum` function).

Example:

```
cow <- function(colnr, x){#colnr is number of column you want zero, x is vector of length 14
    all(x[-colnr] > 0) & x[colnr] == 0)
}
horse <- function(colnr){#produces sequence of Trues and Falses telling you which columns satisfy the condition
      apply(yourdataframe, 1, cow)
}

#example output:
horse(1)

#while we're at it: create a vector of length 14 containing the number of rows satisfying the 14 conditions:
sapply(seq(1:14), horse)
```

The `1` in `apply` is because you want to apply to rows, not columns. The function `sapply` is like apply but then applying a function to each element of a vector rather than each row of a dataframe.

Update: this answer is the same as zyunaidi's which appeared while I was typing.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data from `zyurnaidi` you can do this.
Find all `0` values in your data.frame using `which` with array indices set on `TRUE`, then remove duplicated rows (`0` in other columns) and count the occurence per column:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(replicate(14, sample(0:5, 1000, replace = T)))
a <- which(df == 0, arr.ind =  T)

table(a[ !(duplicated(a[, 1]) | duplicated(a[, 1], fromLast=T)), 2]) 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 
18 26 19 14 11 20 21 10 24 21 15 11 22 11
```